# Creating a generic list using class object in java

Tags: java, reflection

I have a function which i want to make generic. 
I want below code

```
public String list(){
    List<EMovieCategory> dataList = DBCompanyContent.getInstance().getDataByDocType(EMovieCategory.class);
    return "";
}
```

Be something like

```
public String list(Class cls){
        List<WHAT TO WRITE HERE > dataList = DBCompanyContent.getInstance().getDataByDocType(cls);
        return "";
    }
```

I couldn`t figure out what to write inside List<***>

Comment: You should find some tutorial about Generic type in Java. Because if you get an answer, you might not understand it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use a type variable:

```
public <T> String list(Class<T> cls){
    List<T> dataList = DBCompanyContent.getInstance().getDataByDocType(cls);
    return "";
}
```

You might need to bound the type variable, if the `getDataByDocType` requires instances of `Class` within a certain bound:

```
public <T extends SomeClass> String list(Class<T> cls) {
```

OTOH, if you're not actually using the fact it's a list of `T`s:

```
public String list(Class<?> cls){
    List<?> dataList = DBCompanyContent.getInstance().getDataByDocType(cls);
    return "";
}
```

or you don't even need a variable at all, if you're not going to use it:

```
public String list(Class<?> cls){
    DBCompanyContent.getInstance().getDataByDocType(cls);
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The part between the `<>` is what data types the List will be storing. You'll be inputting what data type `getDataByDocType(cls)` returns.